# How to set alignment for WKInterface Label using setAttributedText

Tags: swift, setattribute, xcode-6.2, nsparagraphstyle, wkinterfacelabel

I'm trying to set alignment for `WKInterfaceLabel` using `setAttributedText` function. Here is my code:

```
 var paragraphStyle = NSParagraphStyle.defaultParagraphStyle()
 paragraphStyle.alignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
 var attributedDictonary = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.greenColor(), NSParagraphStyleAttributeName:paragraphStyle]
 var attributeString = NSAttributedString(string: "TextAttributed", attributes: attributedDictonary)
 self.titleLabel.setAttributedText(attributeString)
```

But I got a problem with this line:

```
paragraphStyle.alignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
```

I got error: `Cannot assign to 'alignment' in 'paragraphStyle'`

How to set alignment for `WKInterfaceLabel` using `setAttributedText`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `NSMutableParagraphStyle`:

```
var paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
paragraphStyle.alignment = NSTextAlignment.CenterTextAlignment
```