# WKInterfaceLabel Text Alignment?

Tags: ios, watchkit, apple-watch, wkinterfacelabel

In InterfaceBuilder there's a property for Text Alignment, although it can't be found between the WKInterfaceLabel class defined properties.

When I set it to any of the alignments it works, except for the Justified one, why is that the case?

[image: watch screenshot]      [image: InterfaceBuilder screenshot]

Is there anything I'm not aware of regarding this weird behaviour?

Comment: I believe that justify doesn't exist on WatchKit because the screen is too small. The UI configuration is available in the storyboard but not in code because most of the UI is stored on the watch itself.

Comment: Justified text in a `WKInterfaceLabel` hasn't worked for me either. Schemetrical's guess is a good one. Otherwise, it seems like a bug.

Answer (score 0):

Actually if you try on UILabel, the justify don't work either. So it is really not a watchapp related issue. You can try using `NSAttributedString` instead.

Comment: Create new project, go to storyboard. Add a UILabel on it with long text. Select Justify alignment in the settings-> text remains as Left aligned.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29742863/how-to-set-alignment-for-wkinterface-label-using-setattributedtext